# Skyrim house not being furnished

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

Hi I am playing Skyrim on Xbox 360 and I built the house by Dawnstar. I payed my housecarl to furnish everything and its been almost 2 weeks and only a couple chest and a table with some barrels have showed up. So I read some things and there was something about not being able to trust housecarls? Is there something I'm missing because I spent all my money and have got nothing as of yet. Please help.

Comment: The slowness is due to how the furnishing pace works.  You need to visit your property frequently or deliberately trigger zone changes.  I have expanded on Despato's answer with more details.

Answer (score 4):

The [UESP wiki page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Personal_Steward) states that the process of paying a housecarl to furnish a home is a **very** slow one. Since you said that some furnishings have already appeared, it is probable that you did not waste your gold, and that it is just taking a long time.

Per [notes at the UESP page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Personal_Steward#Notes_2):

> The amount of time it takes for stewards to furnish your house depends
>   on the number of times you leave the area.

So if you only visit your house once in a while, it will take a LONG time to finish.  The USEP page has further details on how to improve the furnishing speed:

> The fastest way to complete the process is to find the border of your
>   property and cross it repeatedly until the furnishing is done (PC
>   players can quickly find the border using the tb console command).
>   There are several areas where this can be performed, including:
>
> > Lakeview Manor: Go South from your entrance door. After the carriage
> >     driver and just before the small pond next to Pinewatch are two large
> >     trees growing next to the rocks on your right. The border is between
> >     the trees.
> >
> > Windstad Manor: Go straight east from your entrance door,
> >     up the hill. The border is between the two trees growing next to the
> >     rocks on your left. (There is a third tree on your right.)
> >
> > Heljarchen
> >     Hall: Go straight south towards Loreius`s farm and pass your stable
> >     and carriage driver. Where the rocks on your right end are two blue
> >     mountain flowers. One of them is growing next to a dead branch. The
> >     border is between the two flowers.

Additionally, you must pay your housecarl to furnish each room in your house **individually**, meaning that if you only paid for one room, it is the only one that will be automatically furnished. The cost for each room is a follows:

- Small House: 1000 gold
- Entry Room: 1000 gold
- Main Hall: 3500 gold
- Alchemy Laboratory: 2500 gold
- Armory: 2000 gold
- Bedrooms: 2000 gold
- Enchanter's Tower: 2500 gold
- Greenhouse: 1500 gold
- Kitchen: 1500 gold
- Library: 1500 gold
- Storage Room: 1000 gold
- Trophy Room: 1500 gold

As for your question about being able to "trust" a housecarl, I do not believe that there is any such function in Skyrim.